# SQL Count Calculations

Tags: sql

TABLE CMC

```
ID CMD USERID STATUS
1  94    4     1
2  102  24     1
3  36   32     1
4  44   40     1
5  82   2      1 
6  66   27     1
7  94   56     1
8  102   2     1
```

TABLE CCC

```
ID COURSEID CMD 
1     2     94     
2    16     102
3    8      82
4    5      94
5    4      66  
6    8      36
7    2      56
8    19     44-
```

TABLE CMD

```
ID  COURSEID
44    5    
66    3   
102   16   
82    5   
94    8  
56    4   
66    2   
36    19
```

Iam trying to create an sql query with status calculations:

```
COUNT(CMC.USERID)  COURSED  COMPLETED  INPROCESS  NOTSTARTED
```

**COMPLETED : If COUNT(CMC) == COUNT(CCC) for that particular COURSEID**

**INPROCESS : If COUNT(CMC) >0, but not equal to COUNT(CCC)**

**NOTSTARTED : If COUNT(CMC) =0**

Could anyone suggest me with the below query :

```
SELECT count(cmc.userid),

(SELECT count(ccc.id) FROM ccc HAVING count(cmc.userid) =  count(ccc.id) ) AS "completed"
(SELECT count(ccc.id) FROM ccc HAVING count(cmc.userid) >0  AND count(ccc.id) !== count(cmc.userid) ) AS "Inprocess"
(SELECT count(ccc.id) FROM ccc HAVING count(cmc.userid) =  0 ) AS "Notstarted"

FROM 
cmc 
WHERE status = 1
```

Comment: Please show your desired results.  Your rules don't make sense. For instance, only one table has `courseid`.  What is the relationship between the tables?

Comment: I have one more table between these two tables, i will update it now

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff - I had updated the table.

Comment: Could anyone suggest me with the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to do the summary in a sub-select statement.  Then I can troubleshoot it easier.  Here is the finished query (if I understand your question correctly):

```
SELECT UserId, 
    CASE WHEN CMCount=CCCount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Completed, 
    CASE WHEN CMCount>0 and CMCount<>CCCount THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InProcess,
    CASE WHEN CMCount=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NotStarted
FROM (
    SELECT CMC.USERID AS UserId, COUNT(CMC.CMD) AS CMCount, COUNT(CCC.CMD) AS CCCount
    FROM CMC LEFT JOIN CCC ON CMC.CMD=CCC.CMD
    GROUP BY CMC.USERID
    ) AS Summary
```

Comment: It shows syntax error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS "Completed",
    CASE WHEN CMCount > 0 and CMCount <> CCCount THEN 1 ELSE 0 ' at line 2

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I forgot to end my case statements.  I updated the code (above).